# Image of elements of $S_n$ in the Temperley-Lieb algebra

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, knot-invariants, quantum-groups

Consider the algebra $A_n$ generated by $u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1}$ subject to relations $u_i^2=-2u_i$, $u_iu_{j}u_i=u_i$ for $|i-j|=1$ and $u_iu_j=u_ju_i$ for $|i-j| \geqslant 2$. The algebra $A_n$ is the  Temperley-Lieb algebra. This algebra has a basis consisting of reduced words $u_I=u_{i_1}\ldots u_{i_k}$.

There is a surjective homomorphism $\varphi\colon \mathbb{C}[S_n] \twoheadrightarrow A_n$ given by $(ii+1) \mapsto u_i+1$. The question is the following: is there any nice description of $\varphi(w)$ for $w \in S_n$? Is it true that $\varphi(w)$ is the linear combination of different $u_I$ with coefficients $\pm 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing has to do with the $n$th tensor power of the $2$-dimensional standard representation $V_1$ of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ along with the commuting action by $S_n$. More precisely, the images of $U(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}))$ and $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$ in the algebra $\operatorname{Hom}(V_1\otimes V_1\otimes\dots\otimes V_1)$ where there are $n$ factors in the tensor product, are the subalgebras involved in Schur-Weyl duality.  The Temperley-Lieb algebra $A_n$ (with loop value $-2$, as in your presentation of it) describes the subalgebra corresponding to the image of $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$.

Let's spend some time going through how this works.  First of all, let $V_1=\mathbb{C}^2$, where $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, thought of as traceless $2\times 2$ matrices, acts on $V_1$ by the usual matrix-vector multiplication.  We'll let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be the standard basis for $V_1$.  There is an invariant nondegenerate bilinear form $\beta:V_1\otimes V_1\to \mathbb{C}$ given by
$$
\beta(v\otimes w)= v^T\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}w
$$
(and in fact, all other such forms are a scalar multiple of this one).  With respect to the basis, we can write this as $\beta=e_2^*\otimes e_1^*-e_1^*\otimes e_2^*$.  There is a sort of "inverse" $\alpha:\mathbb{C}\to V_1\otimes V_1$ to this defined by
$$\alpha(1)=-e_2\otimes e_1+e_1\otimes e_2.$$
I'm more comfortable with explaining the following with some graphical tensor notation, but I'll also give some algebraic formulae in parallel.  We'll represent $\beta$ and $\alpha$ by

[image: "coupons" for beta and alpha]

These satisfy the following identities:

[image: identities the "coupons" satisfy]

We can write the first as $(\beta\otimes\mathrm{id})\circ(\mathrm{id}\otimes\alpha)=\mathrm{id}$, the second as $(\mathrm{id}\otimes\beta)\circ(\alpha\otimes\mathrm{id})=\mathrm{id}$, and the third as $\beta\circ\alpha=-2$.

By the way, where $\beta$ comes from is an isomorphism between $V_1$ and its dual representation $V_1^*$, and then $\alpha$ comes from the inverse of the matrix for $\beta$.

There's a convention for the Temperley-Lieb algebra (I believe due to Kauffman) where you draw the above diagrams as curves with isolated critical points, where each critical point is interpreted as $\alpha$ or $\beta$ depending on the sign of the second derivative.  With this convention, the above diagrams look like

[image: diagrams as curves]

This lets the diagrams be more concise while letting our topological intuition help us perform calculations: you can "pull strings straight"!

With some of the background out of the way, what I want to do is write the swap homomorphism $\tau:V_1\otimes V_1 \to V_1\otimes V_2$ defined by $\tau(v\otimes w)=w\otimes v$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Writing $\tau$ as a "crossing" in a diagram, we can verify the following identity holds:

[image: identity involving transposition]

Algebraically, this is that $\tau=\mathrm{id}+\alpha\circ\beta$.

Now let's spell out the correspondence between $A_n$ and the above so-called string diagrams.  We set

[image: u_i as a diagram]

and define a multiplication operation by vertical stacking.  Hence, $u_i^2=-2u_i$ since that forms a closed loop in the diagram, and $\beta\circ\alpha=-2$:

[image: u_i^2=-2u_i]

There is an obvious homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[S_n]\to \operatorname{Hom}(V_1^{\otimes n})$ given by sending a permutation to the induced permutation of the tensor factors. The above identity that $\tau=\mathrm{id}+\alpha\circ\beta$ says that this homomorphism is equivalently given by sending the transposition $(i\ i+1)$ to $\mathrm{id}+u_i$.  Hence, the homomorphism surjects onto $A_n$.

It turns out that a basis for $A_n$ corresponds to all possible ways of connecting $n$ points to $n$ points with curves that don't cross (counted by the Catalan numbers).  For example, here are the five diagrams that form a basis for $A_3$:

[image: A_3 basis]

Algebraically, we can give these as
$$\{1,u_1,u_2,u_1u_2u_1,u_2u_1u_2\}$$

As a partial answer to your first question, the graphical presentation of elements of $A_n$ gives a nice way to calculate the images of elements of $S_n$, since the graphical notation gives a canonical way to describe a basis: they are the elements where each strand has 0 or 1 critical points.  The data of such an element is simply the pairs of endpoints for each strand.  For example, an expansion of an element of $S_3$:

[image: image of (1 3 2)]

I'm not familiar with any nice formulas, though, for finding the coefficient of a particular basis element for a specific element of $S_n$.

**The answer to your second question is no.**  In $S_4$, the image of $(1\ 3)(2\ 4)$ has a coefficient of $2$ in front of $u_2$.  Here's an expansion of this permutation into its sixteen terms, with the ones evaluating to $u_2$ highlighted in yellow:

[image: expansion of (1 3)(2 4), highlighting the u_2 terms]

Since loops give a factor of $-2$, we see the coefficient of $u_2$ is $1+1-2+1+1=2$.

We could have avoided writing all sixteen diagrams by thinking about what choices need to be made at each crossing to achieve $u_2$.  You know that $u_2$ involves certain boundary points being connected together in a certain pattern, so you could start by, for example, finding all paths that connect the bottom left corner to the upper left corner, then recursing for each strand of $u_2$.

(By the way, some [useful notes by Scott Morrison](https://tqft.net/math/JonesWenzlProjections.pdf) about diagrams for the Temperley-Lieb algebra.)